# Rails undefined method form fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add dynamic fields to my rails application.
I have a fields_for

```
<%= form.fields_for :books do |book| %>
    <%= render 'book_fields', form: book %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Field", form, :books %>
```

When it renders book_fields I am getting the following error 
[image]

If I am passing form in render why would I be getting this error?

I have tried book.label :title but I get the same error but instead of the undefined varaible being form it is book. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
<%= form.fields_for :books do |builder| %>
  <%= form.label :title %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<% end %>
```

If I remove the partial render and stick the form text fields and labels into the fields_for itself it works. While rendering the partial, that is when I get the error.

Comment: Can you add more details, that book object should be a FormBuilder, maybe you're shadowing some variable.

Comment: How can I check that? I'm sort of new to Rails.

Comment: Does the fields_for work without rendering the partial, just "inline"?

Comment: Yes. See question update.

Comment: You're using the same outer variable outside in the fields_for block, try with `builder` instead `form`.

Comment: No luck with builder either. I need for this to render the partial do I can add dynamic fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154924/discussion-between-trenton-tyler-and-sebastian-palma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using the `form` block variable as the local in your render method, you have to use the `builder` one, like:

```
<%= form.fields_for :books do |book| %> 
  <%= render 'book_fields', f: book %> 
<% end %>
```

In the partial:

```
<fieldset> 
  <%= f.label :title %> 
</fieldset>
```

The error is happening because you're using your "main" form variable, and when the partial is being load, Rails try to find it as a local variable, which doesn't exist in that context.